# Kubernetes Ingress can't find SSL secret created by CertManager

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, cert-manager

I have been trying to genereate an SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt to my domain but cert-manager creates the secret and adds a random suffix, causing the NGINX ingress controller to not be able to find it:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/issuer: scaleway
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: <DOMAIN>
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: my-svc
                port:
                  number: 80

  tls:
    
  - hosts:
    - <DOMAIN>
    secretName: tls-cert
```

Here is the error in the NGINX logs :

```
Error obtaining X.509 certificate: no object matching key "default/tls-cert" in local store

Error getting SSL certificate "default/storek8s.igesa.it": local SSL certificate default/storek8s.igesa.it was not found. Using default certificate
```

The secret is always created like this :

```
NAME                                     TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
...
tls-secret-fjrm5                  Opaque                                1      60m
```

How do I disable adding the random suffix for the secret generated by Ingress ? Is there any workaround to solve this ?

Comment: Hi @joe1531, could you answer avinashpancham's questions from the answer? How did you install cert-manager? Did you edit `values.yaml`, if yes what you changed? How did you setup your cluster - some cloud provider solution or bare-metal? Which one? Which Kubernetes version are you using? These information are important to replicate your issue. Could you run `kubectl describe secret tls-secret-fjrm5` and paste output (edit your main question)?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I have too little information to give an exact answer. Are you for example using this [Helm chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/cert-manager/cert-manager), what values does your `values.yaml` contain, and how did you setup your issuer?

Also, I know that `tls` secrets created by cert-manager should be of type `kubernetes.io/tls` and not `Opaque` as is the case in your situation. So there is definitly something going wrong there.